# Not able to align horizontal slider in a row

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a horizontal carousel that is working fine, [here is the code for it](https://jsfiddle.net/learner001/ymrdj6y6/1/)
Now i wish to fetch the data from database and display it that corousel. Following is the code that i used

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
        <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item  active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php foreach($student as $student): ?>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><?php echo $student->fullname;?></a>
                            </div>          
                        <?php endforeach; ?>           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#media" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#media" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
        </div>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

but the view is distorted and instead of all the slides sliding in one row, the view is coming like this

[image]

Comment: why was this tagged as php? it doesn't appear to be a php-related issue.

Comment: why was this tagged as mysql?

Comment: @Fred -ii- i tagged it because i think i may be i am not applying the loop properly

Comment: if it's a php/mysql related issue; do you think you may have syntax errors? Are you checking for them with error reporting and on the query?

Comment: @Fred -ii- yes did but not able to find anything

Answer (score 0):

That's because unless the row is active, the other .item row gets the property `display:none;` If you were to remove the display:none; it should work as you want.

Comment: by removing display:none; still the result is coming same

Answer (score 0):

Create the class="row" inside the loop. Also keep in mind that the screen consists of 12 units only, so if you create a row of more than 12 units it will go to next line automatically. As you have created the loop that creates "col-md-3" for more than 4 times which sums more than 12, so it moves to next line.
For reference view [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Comment: creating a row inside the loop will simply create a vertical row where the data will be one below the other, and although the units are 12 and i have divided it into 4 parts but that is for only one screen, my slider can have any number of boxes as they will be populated from database, but at a time only 4 will be visible

Answer (score 0):

As you have not given the php code, i am giving u sample of it

The array that you are getting divide it into a group of 4 (or as many as you want) like given below

```
$query = $this->db->get('student');
$r = $query->result();
$s = (array_chunk($r, 4));
return $s;
```

And then on the code you have given, change into following

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php foreach($s as  $key => $per_student): ?>
        <?php if($key=='0'): ?>
            <div class="item active">
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="item ">
        <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php foreach($per_student as $student): ?>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><?php echo $student->fullname;?></a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```